# Hit Breakpoint When Caused by the Debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

Is there a way to have breakpoints hit when the action is caused by the Visual Studio debugger?
For example, let's say I have the following (I know you shouldn't do this, just using it for argument's sake):

```
public class Test
{
    int _X = -1;
    public int X { 
        get { return ++_X; } //Breakpoint here
        set { _X = value; } 
    }
}
```

And:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        Test t = new Test();
        t.X = 1;  //Breakpoint here
        return;
}
```

If you pause at the breakpoint in Main, every time you "hover" the mouse pointer over "t.X"
(assuming you have the following Debugging option enabled - "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls") or you evaluate the property in the "watch" window - it will increment the property but the breakpoint in the property's "get" accessor will not be hit. Re-asking the question in a more specific context - is there a way to hit the breakpoint in the property's "get" accessor when the evaluation is done by the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research on this topic, I learned about FuncEval, and after reading lots of things about FuncEval I was led to the following article:
[Stop Mid Func Eval, Nested Break States](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevejs/archive/2005/10/23/484024.aspx) by Mr. SteveJS.
In the article he explained that starting in VS2005 you could hit a breakpoint caused by a FuncEval if the evaluation was done from the "Immediate Window" instead of the Watch or "Quick Watch" windows. So, in the above example, entering

```
?t.X
```

in the Immediate Window caused the breakpoint on the get accessor to be hit.

Answer (score 0):

**Uncheck** this option

**Debugging** -> **General** -> **Step over Properties and Operations**

have a look at this Post as well

- [**Visual Studio Debugging Tips and
  Tricks**](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/visual-studio-debugging-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: @Asad - I don't see that option; I do see "Step over properties and operators (Managed only)" but am I correct in understanding that enabling this will just step over the properties which isn't the desired result? I am not "stepping" when the debugger evaluates the property and changes it's value. Forgive me if I misunderstood what you were trying to say.

Comment: Oh man, sorry, you need to "UnCheck" this option. Debugger will then Step Into Properties. Have modified answered.

Comment: I had that option unchecked when I posted the question. I do not want to step, I want to catch a breakpoint in the property's get accessor. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I rolled back your edit of the title. I am not asking how to step into properties when debugging.